# Django-CMS: cmsplugin_blog in default page

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm having trouble putting the cmsplugin_blog app at the first page in django-cms.

The problems are, among others, that the URL doesn't show the page name, so there are several issues with links to articles and internationalization that don't show up otherwise.

Is it possible to have django-cms redirect to the first page in the menu (let's say /blog/) when asked for the root?

Comment: You can set up manual redirect, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Django CMS page can be hooked to an application module, like your Blog. Have a look at the documentation for App Hooks: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/extending_examples.html#my-first-app-apphook

After you set up a cms_app.py for your blog, you should be able to set your Blog application as the Application for your home/first page in the advanced menu of the CMS page change view.

Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Advanced Settings of the Page menu. There should be a "redirect" field where you can select your blog's root page. Do this for your first page.

What happens is that the root page is replaced by an http redirect and the browser will show your blog's page.